# How to formally write the conditional expecation of $E(X \mid Y,W)$ where $X,Y$ are continuous, but $W$ is discrete?

Tags: probability

If $Y,X$ is a continuous random variable, while $W$ is a discrete variable, how can one formally write the conditional expectation of $E(Y\mid X,W)$?

Normally, if we are just considering the conditional expectation of $E(X\mid W)$, we have:

$$
\operatorname{E} (X \mid W=w )= \int_{\mathcal{X}} x f_X (x \mid W=w) \, \mathrm{d}x
$$

where

$$
f_X (x \mid W=w) = \frac{f_{X, Y}(x, y)}{P(W=w)}
$$

However, in the case of $E(Y\mid X,W)$, would we have:

$$
\operatorname{E} (Y \mid W=w, X)= \int_{\mathcal{Y}} y f_Y (y \mid W=w, X) \, \mathrm{d}y
$$

where

$$
f_Y (y \mid W=w, X) = \frac{f_{Y,X, W}(y,x, w)}{P(W=w, X=x)}
$$

but this doesn't make sense since we are combining discrete and continuous variables. What is the proper way of doing this?

Comment: The density of $Y$ conditional on $W$ and $X$ is given by dividing the joint density of $(Y, X, W)$ by the (mixed) joint density of $(X,W)$. If $X$ and $W$ are independent then you can write the denominator as $P(W=w)f_X(x)$ (where the density of $X$ is either given or obtained by marginalizing the original joint density of the triplet).

Comment: Thanks, if they are not independent, is there a generally correct notation to use? Also, would it be generally easier to write $dP(Y=y\mid W=w, X=x)$ in place of $f_Y (y \mid W=w, X) \, \mathrm{d}y$ for the purposes of convenience and possible manipulation efficiency?

Comment: Not that I know of, however might I suggest to avoid notation like $f_Y(y|W=w, X)$ and instead use $f_Y(y|w,x)$. In short, $\{X=x\}$ is a random event (subset of the sample space $\Omega$) while $f(y|x)$ is a deterministic function of the numbers $y$ dependent on the parameter $x$ which is usually fixed (and when $x$ varies, $y$ is usually fixed like in the LTP: $f(y)=\int f(y|x)f_X(x)dx$). Lastly, I tend to write out all my densities for clarity. For example, with continuous RVs, $Y$, where $P(Y=y)=0$ it would be confusing/ambiguous, personally, to see $dP(Y=y)$ instead of $f(y)dy$.

Comment: You can just assume everything in the world is conditioned on $W=w$, where $P[W=w]>0$.  It is as if you are defining a new sample space $S$ that only includes outcomes $s \in S$ under which $W(s)=w$. So you get $$ f_{Y|X,W}(y|x,w) = \frac{f_{X,Y|W}(x,y|w)}{f_{X|W}(x|w)}$$ You can get $f_{X,Y|W}(x,y|w)$ by differentiating $$P[X\leq x, Y\leq y|W=w] = \frac{P[X\leq x, Y\leq y, W=w]}{P[W=w]}$$

Comment: I originally had in mind that $W\in \{0,1\}$. In such a case, if I were to re-write $f_{X,Y,W}(x,y,w) = f_{W\mid X,Y}(w\mid x,y) f_{X,Y}(x,y)$, does the notation $f_{W\mid X,Y}(w\mid x,y)$ make sense for a binary random variable $W$? I.e., now that the discrete variable is conditioned on continuous variables?

Comment: I mean that $$ f_{X,Y|W}(x,y|w) = \frac{\partial^2 F_{XY|W}(x,y|w)}{\partial x \partial y} =  \frac{\partial^2 P[X\leq x, Y\leq y|W=w]}{\partial x \partial y} $$

Comment: I am wondering how you go from:

$$
\frac{1}{P[W=w]}\cdot \frac{\partial^2 P[X\leq x, Y\leq y,W=w]}{\partial x \partial y} = f(x,y,w)
$$

It seems that because there is the extra $W=w$ term in the derivative, I am not sure how to handle that. Is there an explicit set of rules you could refer me to for calculus and probabilities? Thank you